# Ruby Reporting through Ruport and other tools

Tags: ruby, ruport

I want to write a small reporting tool and looking to fetch data from MySQL. After searching I found a tool called as [Ruport](http://www.rubyreports.org/) but I am not following where are it's binaries located. If not binaries than how to install it. It discusses the installation commands to install via gems, but where are the files located.

Secondly, do I have to create a Windows interface using fxRuby or wxRuby to work with it?

Are there other free reporting tools for Ruby?

Comment: Have you considered that's a library, rather than an executable?

Comment: @Andrew: Where are the files located? Where to download it? Inside Ruby folder or elsewhere?

Comment: Have you installed a gem before, or is this your very first time?

Comment: First time. I am a newbie in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a good idea to get a good book or two on Ruby, rather than asking these kind of questions, but here goes:

To install a gem, do

```
gem install gemname
```

To use it, put the following in Ruby code:

```
require "rubygems" # May not be necessary
require "gemname"
```

To find where your gem files are stored, do

```
gem env
```

And as for whether you need a GUI for ruport: can you try working that out yourself first?